# Redirect URLs of Domain that is already 301 Redirected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I don't even know how to ask this question correctly, because I have never seen it done before. I am pretty competent with editing name servers, creating a records, and cnames etc, but I have no idea if this is even possible.

I have a client that owns a several domains that all point at the same site. So say the main domain is *www.client-site.com.*  So then *www.other-domain-1.com* and *www.other-domain-2.com* are simply set as 301 redirects to point at *www.client-site.com*.

So all is good until now he is requesting that *www.other-domain-1.com/facebook* and *www.other-domain-1.com/linkedin* point to his facebook page or linkedin profiles instead of redirecting to the main domain.

The 301 redirect is happening at the registrar, and I don't believe there is a way to do what he wants from there.  But I am thinking I could instead point it at the web host nameservers and include it as a addon domain, and then use the .htaccess file to do the 301 redirect of only the hostname, and then redirect as desired the hostname/paths.

So what is the proper way to do this? Something like...

```
Redirect 301 http://other-domain-1.com/facebook http://facebook.com/account
Redirect 301 http://other-domain-1.com/linkedin http://linkedin.com/profile
Redirect 301 http://other-domain-1.com http://client-site.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# facebook redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?other-domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^facebook/?$ http://facebook.com/account [L,NC,R=302]

# linked-in redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?other-domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^linkedin/?$ http://linkedin.com/profile [L,NC,R=302]

# rest of the redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?other-domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://client-site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Yes definitely these should be converted to `301` once rules are verified to be working. In testing phase one must not use `301` since bad redirects will also be cached in browsers.

Comment: Your solution only worked after I removed the `?:` from the `(?:www\.)`  Can you explain the `?:` please?  Before I removed them the redirect was simply concatenating the rewrite url onto the main domain like this `http://client-site.com/www.facebook.com` instead of redirecting

Comment: `(?:..)` is called non-capturing group. You can safely remove `?:` in above and it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

So the Solution that worked on my server based on anubhava answer above was

```
facebook redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?other-domain-1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^facebook/?$ http://facebook.com/account [L,NC,R=302]
```

Then after getting them all working changed the `R=302` to `R=301` to make the redirects permanent.

Comment: Please don't post this in the answer section. You can comment below my posted answer or below your question.

Comment: I accepted your answer. But I read stack overflow help before putting in my own answer, and I found it is perfectly acceptable to do so, since **I worked out part of the solution myself.** To me it does not make sense to do it the way you did, if your original answer was right but just does not work on my particular server. Since you edited your answer now some of the comments do not make sense.

Comment: Change of removing `(?:...)` is extremely minor in nature which doesn't change the overall flow of the rules. That's why for minor issue like this should be resolved by leaving comments on an answer. Hope it clarifies. I have already upvoted your question.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I appreciate your help very much. I was not trying to take credit or steal your reputation. ;)

Comment: Yes I very well understand that it wasn't your intention. btw I am surprised why `(?:...)` didn't work for you because that has worked for many on various Apache versions. Let me know your Apache version and I will check with Apache docs why you faced problem there.

Comment: Cpanel reports Apache Version 2.2.24 BUT I now that I think about it I believe Hawkhost actually runs LightSpeed instead of Apache on all of their shared servers.

Comment: oh ok got it so it was `Lightspeed` that didn't like it.